# Decoding a text with percent symbol in Asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

There is a text on my web site html like;

```
&amp;#37;
```

that's about percentage you may know. I can't print it as percent symbol. I've tried Html helper's Raw method;

```
@Html.Raw(item.baslik)
```

but this produces just;

```
&#37;
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means `item.baslik` is already HTML encoded. Try `Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.baslik))` instead. Or better, don't encode your property values prematurely, if you have access to the code.

Comment: vay be ssg ile buradan görüşmek :D

Comment: but are you sure is there any Decode method of Html helper?

Comment: @SerhatKoroglu oops there isn't. I edited my answer :)